# Is Java FX still available?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to install Java FX again from download software section in eclipse. I did the procedure multiple times but this time I'm having troubles finding a Java FX version (eclipse can't even find it in any available site).
Online or from the official site there is no trace of it..
So... it is dead?
Are there any alternatives for Java? (No swing please, it's too old)

Comment: https://openjfx.io/

Comment: *(No swing please, it's too old)* Java itself is older, so what? You can argue it's ugly, but the fact that is old is just no good reason to avoid it.

Comment: In general you do not install libraries via marketplace/software settings. Are you refering to e(fx)clipse?

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 11, OpenJFX is decoupled from the Oracle JDK (this was already the case for OpenJDK), and needs to be installed separately on the Java level. You should not install it in Eclipse, because Eclipse is an IDE, not your Java installation.

To be clear, Java FX is not dead, the decoupling just allows releases to be developed at a separate pace and your Java installation being more modular.

How you install this depends on your operating system.
For example on Arch Linux with the OpenJDK, you install `java-openjfx` from the `extra` repository.